# Java StringTokenizer to split every single char in one line

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I want use StringTokenizer to split every single char in one line. sth like

```
abc {{ }
```

And the expect output is like

```
a
b
c
{
{
}
```

But the Default will split only by white space

```
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line);
```

The output is

```
abc
{{
}
```

How to improve the code
Thank you very much

Comment: Why don't you just use `String#charAt`?

Comment: ... or String@toCharArray() which gives you each character in a nice array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use StringTokenizer. You can just do

```
char[] temp = string.toCharArray(); 
String reassembled = "";
for(int a = 0;a<temp.length;a++)
{
    reassembled+=temp[a]+"\n";    //Adding newline
}
System.out.print(reassembled);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have couple of options to do that.

```
       String data = "abc {{ }";

        //If you want to remove the spaces in between 
        data = data.replace(" ", "");

        //Option - 1 : 
        for(char ch : data.toCharArray()){
            System.out.println(ch);
        }

        //Option - 2
        for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
            System.out.println(data.charAt(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string.split() method.

```
    String a = "abc {{ }";
    String[] b = a.split("");
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i){
        if(!b[i].equals(" ")){
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }
    }
```